# Can't Get The Favicon To Show Up in Safari 14

Tags: html, safari, favicon

I just started learning HTML, and to practice, I was just messing with Sublime Text to make a test website. I added the code for favicons which I have shown below which worked for Chrome, but not Safari.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
<head>
<title>My Website</title>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/Users/umairzubair/Documents/html/image/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/Users/umairzubair/Documents/html/image/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/Users/umairzubair/Documents/html/image/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/Users/umairzubair/Documents/html/image/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/Users/umairzubair/Documents/html/image/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
```

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong and how can I correct it. I would really appreciate it.

Comment: are you running the site on a (local) webserver? Or just opening the file from disk?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is with the file path you are using inside `href` tag.
It should be something like this:
`/image/faviconname.png` instead of the long one.